# PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, pyspark, macos-sonoma

I'm trying to run pyspark code using visual studio code 2, on my MacBook M1 Pro with SONOMA OS and I'm getting the error:

> PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.

I found several references saying that I should make changes to my .zshenv file and include the lines below:

```
if which java > /dev/null; then export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home); fi

if which pyspark > /dev/null; then
   export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/"
   export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
   export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
fi

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v21)
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[3] pyspark-shell"
```

but I still have errors. Does anyone have any different ideas on how to resolve this?

run pyspark code on mac